# iOS Obj-C custom number text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

is there any way to create a custom text field for number? for example, there is 6 digit number input.. Is it possible to create a text field like

```
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

This number field is the one that same as android. Is it possible to achieve it in iOS? I have been searching for quite a while, but couldn't find any clue. I am new to iOS development. Please guide me...........

Thanks!

Comment: can you upload any pic of textfield

Comment: No. It is not possible. If it is necessary you can customize this with UIButtons and UIimages. But better avoid this. If it compulsory set uiimageview under textfield. Next maintain images for each digit. In textField if user enters the second digit programatically  maintain one space. May be you can achieve doing like this. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have swift implementation for this
https://github.com/harshalrj25/stackoverFlowAnswers/tree/master/dashedTextFieldDemo

You can convert it to objective c